# Render is blank, doesn't show what camera sees

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering

Newbie here. I don't know what happened. I was was able to make one render and save it as an image. I moved the camera and added more lights, and the render hasn't worked since. I didn't change any settings or anything, it just stopped working. I even made a new camera and it didn't help. I also changed to F-stop and altered the distance settings. I'm still getting nothing.

Can anyone help?

[image: Camera1]
[image: Render Result]

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: Please share your blend file so that I can take a look at it? You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy + pasting the generated url here.

Comment: @Teja thank you, but after several hours I discovered the problem... I didn't know that hidden objects become visible in a render; there was something in front of the camera blocking the view! I was going crazy trying to figure it out, lol! Thanks.

Comment: MimiBB, in fact your case wasn't covered by the other question being linked here. I edited it so that it covers situations like yours. Good that you figured it out yourself: you can answer your own question if you like.